# Setting up and inserting data in PouchDb on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, pouchdb

Hi Guys im completely new to Ionic 2,

But i know js/ts and all that fun stuff already. Now i want to use PouchDb in my ionic app here is my home.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';  
import cordovaSqlitePlugin from 'pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
}


PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
var db = new PouchDB('test', { adapter: 'cordova-sqlite' });



function setData(data) {
 var todo = {
    title: data,
    completed: false
  };
  db.post(todo, function callback(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Successfully posted a todo!');
    }
  });
}  

function getData() {
  console.log(db.allDocs);
}
```

Here is my first problem `var db = new PouchDb....`is no fuction when I put in a on startup function i get an error because my "setData" function doesnt know what "db" is. How can i fix that? And is my importing stuff right?

Next question do i have to import that stuff in my app.module.ts file too? an do i need a provider?

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen'; 


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I think thats everything for now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the SQLite provider.
Here is a tutorial for setting up the PouchDb In Ionic Using SQLite as the database.

https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/

If you need more help, just comment and I will improve the answer.